# Unable to Install DuckDB using Python PIP

Tags: python, duckdb

Everything goes fine until the following lines:
Installing collected packages: duckdb
Running setup.py install for duckdb ... \

And it is stuck. Nothing moves.
Please, I seek help from Python community members.
Is there any other way to install it if not PIP.
Note: I have very limited access to the UNIX machine where I am installing. And I am installing to a venv.

Comment: Which Python version are you using (please add the output of `python --version` ran from inside of your venv). Which platform the maching is running (please edit your question to add it)? Do you get more information by using `pip install -v`, `pip instal -vv` or even `pip install -vvv` (please edit your question if you find some)? Which version of duckdb is pip trying to install? Also can you run `top` while pip is "doing nothing" to double check it's ... doing nothing?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. The version is 3.6

Comment: This could take a while. Give it some time?

Answer (score 1):

I did not have luck with conda, but duckdb's documentation does say that you can install from conda:

`conda install python-duckdb -c conda-forge`

https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python

I would also verify that you are in the correct env.

Comment: `pip install duckdb` worked fine on one computer, in one conda environment but on a different computer it took ages to resolve and once it had python insisted that it wasn't installed. Your conda tip worked.

Answer (score 0):

You will actually need to wait.

I found that to sucessfully get duckdb for Python 3.6.2 (for a compatibility check of a package I am working on) I needed to pre-install
`pybind11` , `setuptools==59.6.0` and `setuptools-scm==6.4.2`  for the
installation to work.

`pip install duckdb` then takes around 12 minutes to compile from source on a Github Actions Ubuntu runner (so not a straight-forward pip install). But it does successfully install in the end.